# UITableViewCell with image on the right?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there a way to set the UITableViewCell.image to display on the right hand side of the cell instead of the left?  Or will I need to add a separate UIImageView on the right side of the cell layout?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No.  But you can easily add an image view as the accessory view to a table cell for the same effect.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]];
cell.accessoryView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Comment: Will changing the accessory view then overwrite the disclosure indicator?

Comment: Yeah, it would.  If you want that then you have to manually add a UIImageView to your cell on creation.  Or create a subclass for your special table cell that wraps that all up nicely for you.

Comment: There's a small typo in the UIImage method: it should say [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]

Comment: Sorry for awakening this thread but it didn't work off the startline, i had to add `[imageView sizeToFit];` before the release and after setting the accessoryview property, hope this helps :)

Comment: By applying a transform on the contentView you *can* place the imageView on the right.  You also ned to apply a transform to flip the imageView and any labels back.

Answer (score 12):

For simple cases you can do this:

```
cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; // optional
```

This will flip (mirror) the content view placing any imageView on the right.  Note that you have to flip the imageView and any text labels also otherwise they themselves would be mirrored!  This solution preserves the accessory view on the right.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example in **Swift** with the approach of using `accessoryView`:

```
private let reuseIdentifier: String = "your-cell-reuse-id"

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
  }

  cell!.textLabel!.text = "Hello"
  cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "World"
  cell!.accessoryView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"YourImageName")!)
  return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to make a custom cell and will work with standard one, you have as minimum two ways:

1. To use accessoryView.

```c
cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"))
cell.accessoryView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
```

2. If you want to have the right image + accessoryView, then you can add UIImageView outlet to ContentView (example name: rightImage) and change background color of textLabel as Clear.

```c
cell.rightImage.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

in **swift3** and **swift4**, we can use this:

```
cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"imageNmae")!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Subclass UITableViewCell and override *layoutSubviews* and then just adjust the frames of the self.textLabel, self.detailTextLabel and self.imageView views.

This is how it might look like in code:

`MYTableViewCell.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MYTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@end
```

`MYTableViewCell.m`:

```
#import "MYTableViewCell.h"

@implementation MYTableViewCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.imageView.image) {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds) - 32 - 8,
                                          CGRectGetMidY(self.contentView.bounds) - 16.0f,
                                          32,
                                          32);
        CGRect frame = self.textLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 8;
        self.textLabel.frame = frame;
        frame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 8;
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This Soln is for adding different image in each cell....Just a Try

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
}

else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
}
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question?

Comment: The OP already understands how to add an image using the cell's image view, which is all this snippet shows. How to position an image to appear on the right-side is the question.

Answer (score 0):

To Add image @ Right Hand side in the Cell, I would suggest you to create a Custom cell with imageview on right hand side , it will be very useful for you .
and add an empty view to link this nib with customcell class.

Now in your cell's nib file remove the view,add tableViewcell  and in that cell drag & drop an imageView to right hand side.

Now go to the TableViewCell's class say DemoCell , create an outlet and set it with the imageview in the tablecell's nib

Now,in tableview's cellforrowatindexpath method reference your cell  and use it with the nib name like this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
DemoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SettingCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DemoCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
}
```

and set the image as per your requirement

cell.imageVw.img  ....

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image in the accessoryview by calling setFrame method of imageview like this: [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35.0, 35.0)];

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to create your own image, just edit `cell.tintColor`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set the `position` programmatically. Here is the `Swift` version of the solution:

```
image.frame = CGRect.init(
x: self.view.frame.width - image.frame.width*1.1,
y: image.frame.origin.y,
width: image.frame.width,
height: image.frame.height)
```

This will position your image on the right side of the cell.
This solution is adjusting automatically the position according to screen size.
The only down side is when you rotate the device you need to reload your data, but you can just `override` in your `UITableView` class the `didRotate` listener method:

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    _tableView.reloadData()}
```