# UITableViewCell image alignment to the right, possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

when adding an image to table cell, as default it goes to left:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

how can I change it that every image in the UITableViewCell will go automaticlly to the right and the textLabel will be 10px to the left of the image.

Thanks alot!

Comment: i'm afraid you cannot with standar `UITableViewCell` you have to use your own cell then customize it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another way is to create a custom cell and override `layoutSubviews` method.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation CustomCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];

   // grab bound for contentView
   CGRect contentViewBound = self.contentView.bounds;
   // grab the frame for the imageView
   CGRect imageViewFrame = self.imageView.frame;
   // change x position
   imageViewFrame.origin.x = contentViewBound.size.width - imageViewFrame.size.width;
   // assign the new frame
   self.imageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
}

@end
```

Rembember that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to create and reuse `CustomCell` and not `UITableViewCell`.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

// other code here...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. PS: Not imageViewFrame.position.x but imageViewFrame.origin.x

Comment: Great solution! I have used your code for centering the image

Comment: can you please share with your swift variant?

Answer (score 5):

Find the solution here code.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]];
cell.accessoryView = imageView;
```

For your reference.

[UITableViewCell with image on the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780395/uitableviewcell-with-image-on-the-right)

Comment: Thanks 
Narasimha Nallamsetty
;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - cell.imageView.frame.size.width, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, cell.imageView.frame.size.width, cell.imageView.frame.size.height);
[cell.yourTexLabel sizeToFit];
cell.yourTexLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.imageView.origin.x - cell.yourTexLabel.frame.size.width - 10, cell.yourTexLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.yourTexLabel.frame.size.width, cell.yourTexLabel.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: no dude... its not working. also, 'yourTexLabel' is 'cell.textLabel, but he can't recognize it for some reason..

Comment: oh well, dude... i just guessed you were using a cell-subclass of your own... you can't do too much with the standard cell...

Answer (score 1):

Found a better answer from @TomSwift here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616694/1884707

```
cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

By applying a transform on the contentView you can place the imageView on the right.

Answer (score 1):

in swift3 and swift4, we can use this:

cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"imageNmae")!)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a custom `UITableViewCell`. The steps are:

1. Create a new objective-C class that is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, for example `LabeledImageTableViewCell`. Declare *ivars* and *properties* for a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`.
2. In Interface Builder, set the *content* of the `UITableView` to *Dynamic Prototypes*. Drag a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` to a table view cell and position them. Set the cell's class to `LabeledImageTableViewCell`. Connect the outlets of the cell to the `UILabel` & `UIImageView` objects of `LabeledImageTableViewCell`.
3. In the delegate for `UITableView` (usually a `UITableViewController`, sometimes a `UIViewController`) implement the *datasource* methods, for example:

   ```
   //#pragma mark - Table view data source
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       return 1;
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return (NSInteger)[rowData count];
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tvcLabeledImage";
       LabeledImageTableViewCell *cell = (LabeledImageTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[LNCCorrelationInfoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       }
       cell.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageForThisRow.png"];
       cell.myLabel = "imageForThisRow";
       return cell;
   }
   ```

Also, check out the Apple videos from WWDC 2011, **UITableView Changes, Tips & Tricks** and **Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding** (Login required: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/.)