# UITableViewCell with an image on the right side

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, cgrect

I want to show an image on the right side in a UITableViewCell.
I'm using this code, to do it:

```
CGRect imageRect = {80,0,225,44};
UIImageView *uiv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
[uiv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"star%@.png", [[self reataurant] valueForKey:@"stars"]]]];
[uiv setClipsToBounds:YES];
[cell addSubview:uiv];
```

My problem is, that the image is shown in other cells, when i'm scrolling the tableview.
What am i making wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780395/uitableviewcell-with-image-on-the-right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780395/uitableviewcell-with-image-on-the-right)

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that you are re-using cells that already have an image when you do not wish to. Check

a) when you re-use a cell, if it has the star image then remove it.

b) before you return the cell add the star at that point (with whatever test you use to determine if the star should appear).

Answer (score 0):

Those UITableViewCells are reused.  Look in your cellForRowAtIndexPath for

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

If you only want one or a certain set of cells to have this particular layout, you can pass a different cellIdentifier for these cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an image view as the accessory view to a table cell for the same effect.

Here is the sample code for your understanding:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fileName"]];
cell.accessoryView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

And make sure you are reusing cell space of a table view in cellForRowAtIndexPath method by using a cell identifier so that overwritten problem can be eliminated ;)

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row]; 

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Hope that should eliminate your problem of images getting displayed on one another,thanks :)